# Using browsers local storage instead of cookie

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage, session-cookies

I have modal pop-up that asks users if they would like to subscribe to my newsletter. If the user closes the modal I don't want it to appear again. Using a cookie doesn't seem reliable, it often re-appears. I have read local storage is the way to do this but not found any examples. How would I switch my code to use local storage? In the code below the modal appears after 5 seconds.

```
//custom.js
if (!readCookie("close_subcribeModal")) {
    function subcribeModal() {
      $("#subcribeModal").modal("show");
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      subcribeModal();
    }, 5000);
}
```

php page:

```
@if(!isset($_COOKIE['close_subcribeModal']) && @$_COOKIE['close_subcribeModal'] != "1")
<div id="subcribeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="subcribeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" id="subcribeModal__close" class="cancel" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2 class="title">Welcome</h2>
                    <p>Would you like to receive our weekly newsletter?</p>
                    <x-mail.newsletter-subscription />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: If the PHP aspect is important (which it looks like it probably is) you might want to add the `php` tag so the question is shown to the right people.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking js due to it being client side but will add the tag in case it helps.

Comment: Localstorage is in the browser, so you'll need a full javascript solution for this. You won't be able to handle your current requirement with php

Comment: It's notable, that users can empty their local storage when ever they want. `localStorage` can also be problematic because it is accessible from any subdomain too. I'd find cookies more reliable (users can of course empty the cookies as well, or deny them altogether), and you can control the path the cookie is accessble. If your cookie doesn't do the job, you've to take a look at the code which sets the cookie, and maybe ask a new question about the found issues, if you can't fix them on your own.

Comment: @Teemu I am happy to use cookies but found the modal would be constantly re-appearing. Am I missing something?

Comment: The PHP code works as it is (unless the used framework is messing with the code), the issue is in the code which sets the cookie. It's not possible to say why the cookie would be missing or containing incorret value based on the provided example. What ever it is, it's a subject for a new question.

Comment: @Teemu, are you certain that localStorage is shared across domain/subdomain? I don’t have a test computer handy but I’m pretty certain that I ran into issues even just reading between www and non-www, but maybe my memory is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) currently says I'm wrong with this, but I'd recall reading about people sharing a server (web hotels etc.) have crushed into security problems.

Comment: @Teemu What's the correct procedure if I need to add a new question? Do I delete this post? Thanks

Comment: Please don't delete this post, it's a legitimate answerable question, and even if you wouldn't need the answer, maybe there's a future reader who can benefit from the post (though I guess there are already tons of questions about how to use `localStorage`).

Comment: @Teemu Ok understood. Thanks for the help. I'll look into why my cookie isn't working.